# Hijacking my own session in different browsers

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, session-hijacking

I am trying to get logged in my web application with Firefox while I am logged in with chrome.

I want to use the same cookies I have in chrome, append them in Firefox and find myself logged-in.

Is this the correct way to do so?

Comment: It may not work anyway because of different user-agent string or different user agent behavior (different JS handling that may be auto-detected by the Website). Most of the time it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that I had to install a plugin called cookie Editor and add the cookie session.

I found my self logged in using firefox without log in.